# Tokenizing words into a new column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I am trying to go through a list of comments collected on a pandas dataframe and tokenize those words and put those words in a new column in the dataframe but I have having an error running through this, is

The error is stating that AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'apwords'

Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

```
def apwords(words):
    filtered_sentence = []
    words = word_tokenize(words)
    for w in words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
    return filtered_sentence
addwords = lambda x: x.apwords()
df['words'] = df['complaint'].apply(addwords)
print df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to apply the `lambda` function is correct, it is the way you define `addwords` that doesn't work.

When you define `apwords` you define a `function` not an `attribute` therefore when you want to apply it, use:

```
addwords = lambda x: apwords(x)
```

And not:

```
addwords = lambda x: x.apwords()
```

If you want to use `apwords` as an attribute, you would need to define a `class` that inheritates from `string` and define `apwords` as an attribute in this class.

It is far easier to stay with the `function`:

```
def apwords(words):
    filtered_sentence = []
    words = word_tokenize(words)
    for w in words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
    return filtered_sentence
addwords = lambda x: apwords(x)
df['words'] = df['complaint'].apply(addwords)
```

Comment: I tried doing what you and João Almeida suggested but I am getting a TypeError: expected string or buffer now, is that because like what you said I have to define a class that inherits from a string and do my original method? Thanks

Comment: No, it must mean that in your `df['complaints']` you have something else than strings. if you use `df.dtypes` you must have `object` type in front of `complaints` don't you? I think, the most likely is you have missing values (which aren't strings), then before applying `addwords` type `df['complaints'] = df['complaints'].fillna('')` to replace `nan` values by empty strings.

Comment: @ysearka  , would you be able to twist this code to pull a sentence that contain a specific word?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could you describe the input you have and output you desire? That would make it far easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to do this:

```
   df['words'] = df['complaint'].apply(apwords)
```

you don't need to define the function `addwords`. Which should be defined as:

```
addwords = lambda x: apwords(x)
```